# Proving properties of Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ as a subset of $L^2([-\pi, \pi])$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am self-studying a functional analysis course and am stuck at one of the problems that introduces Sobolev spaces in relation to the Fourier series and Hilbert spaces. I am having trouble with

> Let $s \geq 0$. Then $f \in L^2([-\pi, \pi])$ is an element of the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ of order $s$ if
> \begin{equation}
>  \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{|n| \leq N} |\hat{f}(n)|^2 (1+|n|
> ^2)^s < \infty 
> \end{equation}
> Suppose that $f \in C^k([-\pi, \pi])$ and $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$, $f'(\pi) = f'(-\pi)$, ..., $f^{(k-1)}(\pi) = f^{(k-1)}(-\pi)$. Show $f \in H^s(\mathbb{T})$ for $0\leq s \leq k$.

I have tried using [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) on $L^2$ to show that $ \| f \|_{L^2}^2 = 2\pi \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(n)|^2 < \infty$ and [Abel's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) to show that the series of the products converges but run into the issue that $\{(1+|n|^2)^s\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is not bounded. I have also tried to use Fejér's theorem about the uniform convergence of the Cesario-Fourier mean to continuous periodic functions, but am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0\leq s\leq k$.

Because $f^{(s)}$ is continuous on $[-\pi, \pi]$, it is in $L^2(-\pi, \pi])$. Thus, by Parseval, $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} |\widehat {f^{(s)}}(n)|^2 = \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f^{(s)}|^2dt < +\infty\tag{1}$$

If you compute the Fourier coefficients of $f^{(s)}$ by repeatedly integrating by parts, noting that the brackets vanish because of the boundary conditions:
$$\begin{split}
\widehat {f^{(s)}}(n) &= \frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^{(s)}(t)e^{-2i\pi nt}dt\\
&=\underbrace{\left[ -2i\pi ne^{-2i\pi nt}f^{(s)}(t)\right]_{-\pi}^\pi}_{=0}+\frac {2i\pi n} {2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^{(s-1)}(t)e^{-2i\pi nt}dt\\
&\vdots\\
&=(2i\pi n)^s \cdot\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{-2i\pi nt}dt\\
&= (2i\pi n)^s \cdot \widehat f(n)
\end{split}$$
Connecting with  $(1)$, you get that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} |n|^{2s}|\widehat {f(n)}|^2 <+\infty$$
which is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} (1+|n|^2)^{s}|\widehat {f(n)}|^2 <+\infty$$